# Return JSON File from Requests in Python

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I've had some success using the POST requests in the past on other sites and receiving data from them but for some reason I'm having difficulty with the metacritic site.

Using chrome and the developer tools, I can see that when I begin to type in the search bar, it starts a POST request to the following url.

```
searchURL = 'http://www.metacritic.com/g00/3_c-6bbb.rjyfhwnynh.htr_/c-6RTWJUMJZX77x24myyux3ax2fx2fbbb.rjyfhwnynh.htrx2ffzytx78jfwhmx3fn65h.rfwpx3dcmw_$/$'
```

I also know that my headers need to be the following in order to get a response

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"}
```

When I run this, I get a status code of 200 which indicates it worked but my response text is not what I expected.  I am receiving the content of the entire page when I'm expecting json of search results.  What am I missing here?

```
title = 'Grand Theft Auto'

#search request using POST
r = requests.post(searchURL, data = {'searchTerm' : title}, headers = headers)

print(r.status_code)

print(r.text)
```

You can see in the images below what I'm expecting to get.

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1uFu.jpg)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7hkY.jpg)

Comment: typically you can use the `r.json()` method to get the json data, but in this case, it looks like there is none

Comment: Right, when I run that it returns nothing but from Chrome you can clearly see it should be returning something.  Am I not setting a header correctly or url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the difference - maybe GDPR-related since i live in Europe, or because i have set DNT (Do not track) to true in Chrome - but for me, Metacritic autocomplete requests post simply to `http://www.metacritic.com/autosearch` with the parameters `search_term` set to the search value and `search_filter` set to `all` :

[image]

From your screenshots, i think the URL for autocomplete in your browser is constructed with your session id, maybe to avoid stuff like you intend to do :)

So in your case i would try in following order:

- post to the `/autosearch` URL and if that doesn't work
- figure out the session-id to URL-writing logic, then make an initial request in the code to get a session id and work with that

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I tried using the /autosearch URL with no luck.  I'll have to look more into the session-id concept to go down that path.

Comment: That could be a hell of a path, maybe it's less painful to try to fetch the result over an european proxy (if this difference is really GDPR related) - give it a try http://www.freeproxylists.net/eu.html